# Show what's choosen in JavaScript's combobox

Tags: javascript, function, combobox, dropbox

Ok so im new to JavaScript and programing in general so i got this kind of assignment that isnt hard but i still cant manage to figure it out...I need to make combo box in form,and create a div outside that form.Then i need JS function that will show what have i choosed from combo box into that div...

```
<script>
    function omiljeniFilm(){
        var lista=document.getElementById("lista");
        var ispis=lista.options[lista.selectedIndex].text;
        document.getElementById("omiljeni").value=ispis;
    }
</script>
<body>
    <form>
        Izaberi omiljeni film:
    <select id="lista" onchange="omiljeniFilm();">
        <option>Gospodar prstenova</option>
        <option>Hari Poter</option>
        <option>Pobesneli Maks</option>
        <option>Titanik</option>
    </select>    
    </form>
    <div id="omiljeni">
    </div>
</body>
```

I used the same function that i write before for very similar assignment that adds choosen words to forms input element but it doesnt work with this div outside the form...

Answer (score 0):

You need two changes

- To get the select value use the value property
- To set the div text use the innerText property

the function would be:

```
function omiljeniFilm(){
    var lista=document.getElementById("lista");
    document.getElementById("omiljeni").innerText=lista.value;
}
```